# Why do we say besha tova instead of mazal tov?

Tags: blessing, pregnancy-birth, speech-talking

When a person hears that someone is pregnant the traditional response is besha tova, instead of mazal tov. Why is that?

Comment: The Mazal Tov has not yet occurred.

Comment: I've seen different communities use either of those wishes

Comment: A tributary question is "what do we mean when we say מזל טוב at all?".

Comment: @WAF http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/790/why-do-we-say-mazel-tov-shouldnt-we-thank-hashem

Comment: Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, pokemon, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: "be-sha'ah tovah" -- at the right time.

Comment: FYI the expression is not restricted to pregnancies. It applies to almost any future event. I've heard it said often to someone who is engaged (or their parents); someone who plans to buy or sell a house; someone who plans aliyah or another move, and other similar major planned events.

Answer (score 5):

"Mazel Tov" is for something that's happened, like a wedding or a birth.

We recognize not to take healthy pregnancies for granted. To say "mazel tov" would imply "we're sure this will make it to birth", which sadly doesn't always happen. Thus, to show that it's in G-d's hands and not ours, we offer a prayer instead, "may the birth happen at a good time."

Comment: conception itself is certainly a milestone, one which many couples are sadly not able to achieve. We say mazal tov at a bar mitzvah even though the boy has not yet accomplished anything, and may end up being a bad person. Also, can you cite a source for your statements?

Comment: @Pokemon, a bar mitzva boy is now obligated in mitzvahs. That in and of itself is something -- recall that we have a framework of responsibilities, not rights. "Conception is a milestone" -- great, but with the whole reproductive process we have the humility to acknowledge it's not under our control. I have also heard pregnancy news greeted with  "mazel tov, b'sha'ah tova" -- congratulations on the conception, and may it come to fruition. But ask any couple who've -- lo aleinu -- lost a pregnancy if conception that didn't make it was cause for celebration.

Comment: As for sources, I guess it's oral law. Just something I've grown up hearing from a lot of good Jews.

Comment: @Shalom I agree, but in my experience, even among traditional but non-religious Jews, there is also a good amount of ayin-hara-related narishkeit here. Like - don't say mazel tov lest, G-d-forbid, the ayin hara makes it not happen.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/74013/8775

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: Related to @pokemon's question, if that were the case, why would we wish mazal tov on an engagement if they marriage is yet to occur and may not happen?

Answer (score 1):

As [this article](http://www.balashon.com/2015/01/mazal-tov-and-beshaa-tova.html) on Balashon makes clear, *mazal tov* was originally used in the same way as we would say "good luck" in English - ie: an expression of goodwill for an event yet to occur. It was an expression, therefore, that was used when congratulating pregnant women, and not said after the child's birth.

In time, the phrase came to be associated with events that had already transpired, making its pronouncement inappropriate when the event had not yet occurred. In the words of David Curwin, whose article on Balashon I link to above:

> And because it [the phrase, *mazal tov*] became associated with happy
>   events like marriages and *britot*, it eventually transformed into a
>   general phrase of congratulations. So you could say to someone *mazal
>   tov* on something that had occurred entirely in the past. If someone
>   won a contest – you could say to them “*mazal tov*”, even though there
>   was no wish for the future. On the other hand, to say to someone who
>   is about to take a difficult test or have a job interview “*mazal
>   tov*” would be considered strange (even though you would say to them
>   “good luck” in English.)...
>
> After *mazal tov* made the transformation from wish to
>   congratulations, a linguistic vacuum was created. That gap was
>   eventually filled by the phrase “*be’shaa tova*” בשעה טובה, which
>   really has the same meaning as *mazal tov* (literally "at a good
>   hour"), and is used for something up and coming (like a pregnancy or
>   engagement), but doesn't have the “evil eye” aspect of congratulating
>   on something that’s already happened (which isn't an issue after a
>   birth or marriage).

Curwin notes in that article that he has not found a pre-20th century source for the phrase *besha'ah tovah* being used in relation to an event that has not yet occurred. Saying it to a pregnant women would appear to be a very recent development in Jewish tradition.

Answer (score 0):

At a good time or at the right time. Divine providence has a role in birth as HaShem holds the key to birth. Timing seems critical for birthing as well as the soul being brought to life amongst our people.