# Source and reason for a bridal Henna?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, wedding

What is the purpose of the custom of a bridal henna, and what is its source? As a child I was told that it's for good luck, but I wonder if that would be permitted.

(I have a personal theory, which I a have not confirmed. I remember being told that Henna was used as a dye for hair. Perhaps, the bride's hair was dyed as a way of beautifying her for the wedding. It may have started as a happy gathering of women which developed into a ceremony.)

Comment: It is my understanding that this is not a widespread Jewish custom, although I have heard of individual Jews who have done it.

Comment: @ezra It's quite widespread in Mizrahi communities, particularly Moroccans IINM

Comment: @DoubleAA - Cool! Do you have some sort of web page where I could read more about the custom? Come to think of it every couple I've heard of who's done it they've been Sephardi.

Comment: I heard from a friend it was because חנ"ה is an acronym for חלה נידה הדלקת נרות  but needs to be verified

Comment: non jews also make this

Comment: " I was told that it's for good luck, but I wonder if that would be permitted". I can't see this form of "good luck" any worse or better than wishing the couple "Mazal Tov". What's the problem?

Comment: @DanF https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/74013/759

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.hennabysienna.com/jewish-henna.html) seems to provide good information on the ritual. Excerpts:

> Henna use, both for everyday adornment and for ritual purposes,
>   quickly spread throughout the Diaspora and was an established custom
>   among the Jews of Morocco and other North African communities, the
>   Levant and Mediterranean basin, the Arabian Peninsula, and Western,
>   Central and Southern Asia.
>
> In these communities, henna was a crucial aspect of the preparations
>   for a Jewish wedding, and often defined the structure of the wedding
>   festivities, from the beginning (marked by the sending of henna from
>   the groom to the bride) through the climax (the main henna ceremony
>   itself) to the end (when the last remnants of henna wore off the
>   skin). Furthermore, henna was used to mark the actors in a variety of
>   other lifecycle events and passage rituals, such as birth, weaning,
>   entering the school system, puberty, and coming out of mourning. It
>   was also used at holiday celebrations and other happy occasions. The
>   symbolism of henna in these Jewish communities was highly polysemous,
>   but it is clear that it had three overarching functions: first, the
>   henna’s staining of skin was seen as beautifying, both as daily
>   adornment and for weddings; second, the materiality of henna was
>   thought as protective, especially of actors at the center of a passage
>   ritual; third, henna was seen as an aid in transforming and guiding
>   the actors into the structure of their new social roles.

One of my friend's daughters had a henna ceremony last year. Unfortunately, because I was in mourning, then, I couldn't attend, but I would have been curious to see what this was. I guess there must be some video on YouTube or some other web site.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-_LMvPUY-k